# Unable to add leaflet-geosearch to react application

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am attempting to add a searchbar to my react-leaflet map app but to no avail. I am currently being thrown the following errors:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'leafletElement' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeLayer' of undefined

and my component looks like this:

```react
import React, { Component } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import * as ELG from "esri-leaflet-geocoder";
import { Map, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";


class Search extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const map = this.leafletMap.leafletElement;
    const searchControl = new ELG.Geosearch().addTo(map);
    const results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

    searchControl.on("results", function(data) {
      results.clearLayers();
      for (let i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Search">
         <TileLayer
          attribution="&copy; <a href='https://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          url={"http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}
        />
        <div className="pointer" />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Where I then reference the component in my app.js folder. I am unsure as to why these are undefined and how so to implement the search bar.

**edit**:

My app.js file:

```react
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import L from 'leaflet';
import Joi from 'joi';
//import only modules needed or error.
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardText } from 'reactstrap';
import {Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import * as ELG from 'esri-leaflet-geocoder';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import Chart from './components/Chart';
//import Search from './components/Search';



var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'http://pngimg.com/uploads/harp/harp_PNG26.png',
    iconSize: [20, 51],
    iconAnchor: [12.5, 51],
    popupAnchor: [0, -51],
    draggable: true,
});

var myIcon1 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'members.png',
    iconSize: [25, 51],
    iconAnchor: [12.5, 51],
    popupAnchor: [0, -51],
});

var myIcon2 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://static.thenounproject.com/png/852208-200.png',
    iconSize: [25, 51],
    iconAnchor: [12.5, 51],
    popupAnchor: [0, -51],
});

//Joi creates the schema for validation
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    event: Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    venue: Joi.string().min(1).max(500).required(),
    address: Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    dtstart: Joi.string().required(),
    dtend:   Joi.string().required()
});

//Not used unless for posting (Members but can be applied to others.)
const schema1 = Joi.object().keys({
    name:   Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    bio:   Joi.string().min(1).max(500).required(),
    latitude:    Joi.number().required(),
    longitude:   Joi.number().required()
});




//URL declaration, if hostname is localhost, request backend. otherwise URL.
const API_URL = window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ? 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Sessions' : 'https://api.tradmap.live/api/v1Sessions';
const API_URL1 = window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ? 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Members' : 'https://api.tradmap.live/api/v1/Members';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    location: {
        lat: 53.1424,
        lng: -6.266155,
 },
 UserslocationFound: false,
   zoom: 6,

   /* Monitors the state of the users inputs (detects changes). */
   UsersSession: {
     event: '',
     venue: '',
     address: '',
     dtstart: '',
     dtend: ''
   },
   Sessions: [],
   Members: [],

   sendingMessage: false,
   sentMessage: false
 }
componentDidMount() {
  //Grabs the markers from the Thesession API to be displayed.
  fetch(API_URL)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(Sessions => {
       this.setState({
         Sessions
       });
     });

     fetch(API_URL1)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(Members => {
          this.setState({
            Members
          });
        });

  /*Asks user for location via google alert. */
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    this.setState({
      location: {
        lat:  position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      },
      UserslocationFound: true,
      zoom: 15,
      draggable: true
    });
  }, () => {
    console.log("Location not given :(");
    fetch('https://ipapi.co/json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(location => {
          console.log(location);
          this.setState({
            location: {
              lat:  location.latitude,
              lng: location.longitude
            },
            UserslocationFound: true,
            zoom: 15
          });
      });
});

}

formSubmitted = (event) => {
/* prevents the page from refreshing on submit. */
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.UsersSession);
  const UsersSession = {
    event: this.state.UsersSession.event,
    venue: this.state.UsersSession.venue,
    address: this.state.UsersSession.address,
    dtstart: this.state.UsersSession.dtstart,
    dtend: this.state.UsersSession.dtend
  };
  //importing Joi to get the result through validation of the inputs with the schema.
  const result = Joi.validate(UsersSession, schema);
  if(!result.error) {
    this.setState({
      sendingMessage: true
    })
//fetching against API_URL
    fetch(API_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',

      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        ...UsersSession,
        latitude: this.state.location.lat,
        longitude: this.state.location.lng,
      })
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(Sessions => {
      console.log(Sessions)
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        sendingMessage: false,
        sentMessage: true
      });
    }, 4000);
    });
  }
}

/*Updates the state on UsersSession */
valueChanged = (event) => {
  /*declaring event.target as it throws errors in chrome */
  const { name,value } = event.target;
  /*Sets usersSession to be the value defined in inputs */
   this.setState((prevState) => ({
     UsersSession: {
       ...prevState.UsersSession,
       [name]: value
     }
   }))
}
//Sharing of code between React components
  render() {
     const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng]
    return (
      <div className ="map">
      <Map className ="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
      /* tile imported to use over leafletjs*/
         <TileLayer
           attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
           url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
         />

         /* displays marker for when users location is given/found */
         { this.state.UserslocationFound ?

         <Marker
                position={position}
                icon={myIcon}>
         </Marker> : ''

         }
         {this.state.Sessions.map(UsersSession => (
           <Marker
                   position={[UsersSession.latitude, UsersSession.longitude]}
                   icon={myIcon} >
              <Popup>
              <em>{UsersSession.event}, </em>
                  {UsersSession.venue} {'\n'}

                  <Button color="primary" size="sm">More info</Button>
                  <Chart/>
              </Popup>
           </Marker>
         ))}

         {this.state.Members.map(Users => (
           <Marker
                   position={[Users.latitude, Users.longitude]}
                   icon={myIcon1} >
              <Popup style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
              <em>{Users.name}, </em>
                  {Users.bio} {'\n'}

                  <Button color="primary" size="sm">More info</Button>
              </Popup>
           </Marker>
         ))}



       </Map>
       <Card body className="message-form">
       <CardTitle>Welcome to TradMap!</CardTitle>
        <CardText>Please input the details of your Session below.</CardText>

        { !this.state.sendingMessage && !this.state.sentMessage ?
          <Form onSubmit={this.formSubmitted}>
         <FormGroup>
           <Label for="name">Session Title</Label>
           <Input
           /*when the state changes */
             onChange={this.valueChanged}
             type="text"
             name="event"
             id="event"
             placeholder="..." />

             <Label for="startDate">Start Date</Label>
             <Input
               onChange={this.valueChanged}
               type="date"
               name="dtstart"
               id="dtstart" />

            <Label for="EndDate"> End Date </Label>
               <Input
                 onChange={this.valueChanged}
                 type="date"
                 name="dtend"
                 id="dtend" />

                 <Label for="venue">Session Venue</Label>
                 <Input
                   onChange={this.valueChanged}
                   type="textarea"
                   name="venue"
                   id="venue"
                   placeholder="..." />

                 <Label for="Address">Session Address</Label>
                 <Input
                   onChange={this.valueChanged}
                   type="textarea"
                   name="address"
                   id="address"
                   placeholder="..." />
        </FormGroup>

         <Button type ="submit" color="success" disabled={!this.state.UserslocationFound}>submit</Button>
         </Form>
          :
          this.state.sendingMessage || !this.state.UserslocationFound ?
         <img src="loading.gif"></img> :
       <CardText>Thanks for submitting a Session! </CardText>
        }
       </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My index.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import "esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css";


import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.js";
import "esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js";



import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/2wy7v2orwr)

Comment: I was following through that code along with the official tutorial and ended up getting stuck. I'm moreso looking for specific answers about my code.

Comment: The code you have posted is exactly the same with the demo I attached. Therefore, include your code or make a similar demo with your code to be able for others to reproduce and solve your issue

Comment: I will update my question now.

Comment: @kboul I've included all relevant code if you'd like to have a look.

Comment: From a quick look as there is a lot code it seems you are missing the reference to the leafletMap. Do you have  `ref={m => { this.leafletMap = m;  }}` passed into your `<Map>` ? And if you have Search as a separate component, have you imported `<Search>` comp inside  `<Map>` ?

Comment: I am unsure as to what you mean by the first point but I did have <Search> placed within the <Map>, I just had deleted it since.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189130/discussion-between-kboul-and-reggie-snow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are utilizing `React-Leaflet version 2` which introduces a few breaking changes, [this one](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/17e12246a05c3826faf816b00483903e942cd2f0/docs/context.md) probably the major since it affects how a custom component needs to be implemented.

Here is a list of changes:

- wrap a component using `withLeaflet()` high-order component to inject
  the context
- access a map instance via `leaflet` prop, for example: `const {map} = this.props.leaflet;`

**Example**

```
import { Component } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import * as ELG from "esri-leaflet-geocoder";
import { withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";

class Search extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {map} = this.props.leaflet;
    const searchControl = new ELG.Geosearch().addTo(map);
    const results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

    searchControl.on("results", function(data) {
      results.clearLayers();
      for (let i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(Search);
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-krffm4) for your reference